# Mapbox map not loading in the offline mode Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mapbox

I'm trying to download map offline and load it when internet is off but that is not working, here's the code given below :

pubspec.yaml

```
mapbox_gl: ^0.16.0
```

Permissions added in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

<meta-data
    android:name="com.mapbox.token"
    android:value="TOKEN" />
```

screen.dart

```
     MapboxMap(
     accessToken: token,
     styleString: style,
     initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(
       zoom: 15.0,
       target: LatLng(14.508, 46.048),
       ),
     compassEnabled: true,
     myLocationEnabled: true,
     onMapCreated: (MapboxMapController controller) async {
       final result = await acquireCurrentLocation();
               await controller.animateCamera(
                CameraUpdate.newLatLng(result!),
               );
                }),
```

This is how I download the map offline

```
downloadOfflineRegion(
        OfflineRegionDefinition(
          bounds: LatLngBounds(
            northeast: const LatLng(-12.824277, -38.371157),
            southwest: const LatLng(-12.835331, -38.382491),
          ),
          minZoom: 4,
          maxZoom: 24,
          mapStyleUrl: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
        ), onEvent: (DownloadRegionStatus status) {
      if (status.runtimeType == Success) {
        print("SUCCESS");
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
      } else if (status.runtimeType == InProgress) {
        int progress = (status as InProgress).progress.round();
        print("PROGRESS : $progress");
      } else if (status.runtimeType == Error) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
        print("ERROR");
      }
    }, accessToken: token, metadata: {
      "sources": {
        "mapbox-streets": {
          "url": "mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-streets-v7",
          "type": "vector"
        },
        "mapbox-satellite": {
          "url": "mapbox://mapbox.satellite",
          "type": "raster",
          "tileSize": 256
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

And this is how I load again

```
@override
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    try {
      await installOfflineMapTiles("assets/cache.db");
      if (await Utils.isInternetAvailable()) {
      } else {
        await installOfflineMapTiles("assets/cache.db");
        setState(() {
          token = "notoken";
        });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
    }
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

But this shows only black screen like this when internet is off,

[image]

What to do for this issue? Can someone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you resolve this? Please let me know an answer, if yes.